# Is it a good idea to create variables using references?

Tags: php, variables, reference

Example:

```
function create_pets(&$cats, &$dogs){
 $dogs = get_dogs();
 $cats = get_cats();
}
```

so I would call it like:

```
function foo(){
  create_pets($cats, $dogs);

  // here use $cats and $dogs variables normally
}
```

I know that I could just assign a new varible the return value of one of those getter functions, but this is just an example. In my situation there's more than just a getter...

Comment: In the example you showed id say no. But it really depends on the situation.

Comment: You might get more detailed and analytical answers on programmers.stackexchange.com. To be clear though, I think this is an excellent question.

Comment: Or codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Christian Mann: Not really, as this is a general code practices question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as everyone says is "it depends". In your specific example, a "create" function, the code is less obvious to work with and maintain, and thus it's probably a good idea to avoid this pattern.

But here's the good news, there's a way of doing what you are trying to do that keeps things simple and compact while using no references:

```
function create_pets(){
    return array(get_dogs(), get_cats());
}


function foo(){
    list($dogs, $cats) = create_pets();
    //here use $cats and $dogs variables normally
}
```

As you can see you can simply return an array and use [the list language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to get the individual variables in a single line. It's also easier to tell what's going on here, create_pets() is obviously returning new $cats and $dogs; the previous method using references didn't make this clear unless one inspected create_pets() directly.

You will not find a performance difference of using either method though, both will just work. But you'll find that writing code that is easy to follow and work on eventually goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstance. Most of the time you would usually call variables by value but in certain situations where you want to modify a variables content without changing the variable's value in other parts of the code, then calling by reference is a good idea. Other wise if you only want the actual content and only the actual content then calling by value is a better idea. This link explains it real well. http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference.html

Comment: well this is not oen of those cases. I just like the syntax of create(var1,var2) :) and it makes the code slightly more compact